# Is it true that 7-Zip can fail to extract an successfully created archive?

Tags: 7-zip

I remember seeing a highly upvoted answer here stating that sometimes the server log files "fail to decompress" when using the highest compression level in 7-Zip.
Can this happen if 7-Zip doesn't give any errors during the compression phase?

Comment: This is the answer, **false recollection**: https://superuser.com/a/619924/598527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find nothing on the web related to 7-Zip's ultra compression being buggy.

If a 7-Zip archive cannot be extracted, it would most likely be due to file corruption *after* the archive was created.

However, if an archived data is important, you should always test decompression before deleting the originals.

Comment: As stated by OP above this answer is correct in that this is not a "bug" in 7-zip. It is due to the fact that 7-zip is able to create archives that can be opened but not extracted by built-in Windows "zip folder" tools due to it using more advance compression algorithms.  There is no corruption occurring at all and opening the archive with newer tools would work fine. Related: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35719205#35719205