# Upload large file with slow upload speed

Tags: networking, bandwidth, upload, cloud-storage

I am wanting to upload a large file (a Raspbian image that when zipped is 2.4GB) to online cloud storage. However, my upload bandwidth is 1 megabit/sec, which is awful. I'm also assuming that sites will have timeouts, and I've calculated the the upload will take over 5 hours, which will be too long.

I could always go to somewhere like a library to upload, but I'm not expecting their upload bandwidth to be much better than mine...

So, before I try to upload to a site, I would appreciate any suggestions on how I could make this a less painful process.

PS. This isn't urgent - just want to get some ideas :)

Comment: Have you considered splitting the compressed file into multiple parts?

Comment: If those sites allow for large file uploads, they shouldn't have a timeout like that.  What you might have to worry/research more about is if they'll let you upload that large of a file.

Comment: @Tyler No, not really - I would _prefer_ it if whoever's downloading it could just download it as one file, rather than lots of little ones and have to reassemble it. If there aren't any other options, then I would probably end up splitting it...

Comment: You can try something like 7zip and set the compression level to ultra. That should reduce the size a bit. https://superuser.com/questions/281573/what-are-the-best-options-to-use-when-compressing-files-using-7-zip . But as @computercarguy said, I'm not sure why you're assuming the sites have a timeout. I would just try uploading it overnight and see what happens...

Comment: @wysiwyg The file is compressed using 7zip with the compression level set to Ultra, so I think that's about as small as the file can get. I guess I could give it a go - Google Drive allows for files up to 5TB to be uploaded!

Comment: @computercarguy Apparently, Google Drive's max file upload size is 5TB, so I think I'm in the clear with that one :)

Comment: FTR, uploading videos to YouTube is painfully slow, easily an 8-hour process even for short (high-quality) videos, but it works fine as long as I leave the webpage open. File sharing sites expect consumer upload speeds to be slow, and must account for that as part of their business model --- if they allow uploading large files at all.

Comment: Anecdotally, when I first set up Backblaze, the initial upload took three months... with no apparent issues, even through reboots, OS updates etc etc.