# Is there a way to choose between single-thread and multi-thread compression in 7z command line tool?

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

Is there a way to choose between single-thread and multi-thread compression in 7z command line tool?

I want to be able to make the choice so that a process that's meant to run in the background with a dozen others do not cause issue with user experience; but when a process is meant to be the main task, such as when re-organizing a database, I want to be able to let 7z use as many threads as are available.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1727122/varying-archive-size-under-multi-threaded-compression) talks about `-mm1` switch but I cannot find it in the [reference documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/index.htm).

Comment: `-m` are compression method parameters. They are described on a different page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document you link contains the information you're asking for:

https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#ZipMultiThread

> mt=[off | on | {N}]
> Sets multithread mode. If you have a multiprocessor or multicore system, you can get a speed increase with this switch. This option affects only compression (with any method) and decompression of BZip2 streams. Each thread in the multithread mode uses 32 MB of RAM for buffering. If you specify {N}, 7-Zip tries to use N threads.